# How to uncompress a gzipped partition image and dd it directly to the destination partition without writing to current partition?

Tags: pipe, dd, gzip, tee, cloning

I've backed up a partition using `sudo dd bs=8M if=/dev/sda2 | gzip > /someFolderOnSDB/sda2.img.gz`.

The image is stored on a separate disk `sdb`.
When restoring it using `gunzip -k /mnt/bkp/sda2.img.gz | sudo dd of=/dev/sda2`, I noticed that the image is being unzipped into the folder `someFolderOnSDB` where the gz file is, and I think is simultaneously being written with `dd` to `sda2`.

I don't want that. I want the unzipping to happen in memory, rather than on `sdb` and the portions being unzipped get directly written to `sda` with `dd`.

The unzipped image is 300GB in size. I considered using `tee` or/and the redirect operator `>`, but am unsure how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by instructing `gunzip` to write the decompressed data to its standard output:

```
gunzip -c /mnt/bkp/sda2.img.gz | sudo dd of=/dev/sda2
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks. I assumed writing to standard output was to show output on the terminal. During the write, around 700MB of memory slowly shifted from RAM to swap space. Total RAM occupied was eventually just 245MB. Wonder why it happened. I guess I should've used `bs=8M`.

Comment: For efficiency you'd probably want `dd iflag=fullblock bs=8M` or `cat`